# Both If and else statement are executed when i use header in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am facing this unusal problem where both the if and the else blocks are being executed if I use a Header in any of the 'if' or 'else' blocks.
The login form is on file admin_login.php
I am using the file login.php for setting a session id if user exists and then redirecting them to admin.php .
else it should destroy the session and redirect back to admin_login.php 
Here i am only echoing from the else block to check.

This is the code from admin_login.php

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="loginImg">
        <img src="images/admin login.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <?php 
        if($_GET['login']=='0'){
            echo '<div class="msgDiv alert alert-danger">Sorry invalid username or password.</div>';
        }
    ?>
    <div id="loginForm">
        <form method="POST" action="login.php">
            <h4>Username</h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br>
            <h4>Password</h4>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="loginButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code from login.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('connection.php');
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$clean_username=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
$clean_password=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);

$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
if(!$result){
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
}
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id']=$row[2];
    echo "<br/> session id:".$_SESSION['id'];
    header('Location:admin.php');
    // exit();
}else{
    echo "Something from the else block" ;
    // session_destroy();
    // header('Location:admin_login.php?login=0');
}

?>
```

And when i login using correct credentials i get redirected to admin.php but the else block also works and the echo statement from if block doesnt work.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHPM.png)

Comment: It doesn't look like the `if` block is executed at all, just the `else` block.  Which makes sense given those notices, since that SQL query probably doesn't find any matching rows.

Comment: then how was it redirected at all ? @David

Comment: According to the screen shot you provided, it *wasn't* redirected.  The page loaded and the `echo` in the `else` block was executed.  If the redirect was issued, the page wouldn't have loaded and you would have gone directly to the redirected page.

Comment: I am sorry i meant how was the header command executed ? and what is a solution to this ?@David

Comment: you need a die(); after the header() in each case. also checking $row is bad you should perhaps do something like checking the num_rows or something instead.

Comment: @BhanuSanghi: The screen shot shows that the `header()` command *wasn't executed*.  If it was, you would have been redirected and the page wouldn't have been displayed.  The behavior you think you're describing *isn't actually happening* so there is no "solution" to this.  It's not clear at all what actual problem you're facing here.  You seem convinced that both the `if` *and* `else` blocks are being executed, when it's clear that they are not.

Comment: Sir pls look once again the header cmd was executed and the page admin.php was loaded and the notices and the echoed statement were produced on the admin page. This is completely unusual and I have been trying to solve this from hours. Sir any kind of help wud be appreciated.I also tried using the die and num_rows but nothing changed @david

Comment: @BhanuSanghi: If there's a problem with the code in `admin.php`, perhaps you can share that code in the question?

Comment: Got it Rsolved ty for your responses every one.

Answer (score 0):

*and the echo statement from if block doesnt work..* How it will work, as it is going to **admin.php** then, why it will echo in **login.php**. And, don't use `echo` where you are using `header('location:somePage.php');` Otherwise, **Cannot Modify Header** error will come.

And, one more thing, you have given `echo` in `else` statement which is *Something from the else block*. And, As i see in screenshot of admin.php, message coming *Something from the ELSE block*. So, What i think is, In **admin.php** somewhere you have written this message *'Something from the ELSE block'*, which is getting printed.

I've edited your code.

**login.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('connection.php');
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$clean_username=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
$clean_password=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);

$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

if($result){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id']=$row[2];
            header('location:admin.php');
    }

} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    echo "Something from the else block" ;
    // session_destroy();
  // header('Location:admin_login.php?login=0');
}
?>
```